# How anonymous would this be?

Tags: anonymity, tor

I use a laptop running tails/tor to go to a public wifi spot like a coffee shop and set up a new email account on protonmail. Then I take that laptop to a park in the middle of the night where there's an xfinity hotspot and sign up for the free hour pass using that email. No cameras, no people, no harddrive in the laptop. Then dispose of the laptop after use.

Comment: This depends on where you live, how much of a suspect you already are, what you a actually do in this one hour and especially how much information you exchange during this time might be directly or indirectly associated with you, if you carry other devices like smartphones etc.

Comment: Oh good point about having other devices with you thats smart to leave those at home! Let's assume no logins, no personal information used, and i'm not a suspect. the missions sole purpose to download torrented software or sensitive documents or something. Could the isp identity you past being a tor user on their network? Even if the nsa or fbi wanted to figure out who i was wouldnt they get stuck at "some random person in a park at this time of day?"

Comment: Anonymous *from whom*?

Comment: From the isp and government agencies

Comment: @thatsmynickityname Nearly impossible to say. Do they have a reason to suspect you? Do they have a reason to suspect someone in your geographical area? Did you happen to use Tor nodes controlled by three letter agencies? what is the storage policy on cameras in your area? What's the storage policy on ...?

Comment: I totally get that. But even the worst case scenario (let's asume there are no cameras) a government agency is controlling the nodes, they know i use tor at home (but lots of people do). The gov see the true ip address which is connected to a hotspot in a public area, then they get a warrant to have the isp fork over the location (assuming the isp can even find my real location on a hotspot?) then even if the gov can find what type and model of computer was used etc, they knock on my door with a warrant out of suspicion, then don't find a laptop because it's gone. how isnt that 100% anonymity?

Comment: @thatsmynickityname: If the government already suspects you they might use more traditional ways to track what you do, like observations, tracking your car, bugging the laptop you use etc. It is mainly a question if the effort is worth it. Don't assume the digital anonymity means anonymity in general. See also https://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: That's a really good point! On the digital side of things though, are there more steps I can take in being annonymous with this setup?

Comment: **No cameras, no people** !! you must be teaming up to be sure of your _intels_

Comment: No cameras, no people sounds just like Finland... but also no hotspots. ;)

Comment: I think that your desire for 100% anonymity is not what you should be asking. That's too big and multifaceted (e.g. you could do all that you said, then log into to the download site with an account that uses your real name). Because all your details are about identifying ***the laptop and the connection before, during, and after the download***, then I would suggest rewording this, and your approach, to that. But then, it really becomes easy for you to work the answer out.

Answer (score 3):

Let's examine your risk factors step by step:

*I use a laptop running Tails/Tor*

This is a solid anonymization between you and the end user. Provided of course you don't overtly supply identifying information.

*set up a new email account on protonmail*

ProtonMail requires an alternate Email, SMS, or Donation to get past their anti-spam human check (At least using Tor they do). Both SMS and Donation are a direct link to you so that leaves an alternate Email. What's the trace on that alternate Email?

*go to a public wifi spot, like a coffee shop*

You laptop MAC address is potentially recorded in the coffee shop router. It's possible you spoofed it, and finding that particular coffee shop and correlating the MAC with other activities is a pretty low probability, but technically possible.

*laptop to a park in the middle of the night where there's an Xfinity hotspot and sign up for the free hour pass using that email.*

Many parks are closed at night, so you will stand out to any park cameras and security. Xfinity will have your MAC, again unless spoofed. If you have in the past or ever in the future reuse your MAC on Xfinity or Coffee shop outside of Tails, correlation is possible, albeit again a pretty high bar.

**Increased complexity is not necessarily better. In many cases it's actually worse.**

The whole Park/Xfinity thing not only doesn't help, it's detrimental. If you are already running Tails and connecting to Proton Mail, just do your download then and there. Attribution back to the coffe shop is protected by Tor. Additional skulking doesn't help, it hurts. There's no reason to destroy your laptop under this scenario, but you certainly can if you like.

Comment: That's really informative and helpful, thank you! A couple things though, I know for sure protonmail doesn't require another email to set it up, it asks for a backup email but you can refuse. I was planning on setting that up at the coffeeshop on tails then taking the laptop to a park with no cameras. Also why wouldnt it be better to use a different public wifi than where the email was setup? Couldn't the gov agency get protonmail to fork over the ip? It seems like coffeeshops would have more cameras than a park.

Comment: Xfinity wifi can be found in places near where I live in the middle of a field, far away from people and cameras, somewhere i could ride my bike to with no traffic lights along the way. Isnt that better than a coffee shop? And i didn't know that about the isp knowing your MAC address! Does spoofing work to keep you annonymous? What all does the isp i use know about my tor usage spoofed vs nonspoofed? And can that information be used to identify me? Sorry I know I have a lot of questions, just trying to soak up as much info as possible.

Comment: @thatsmynickityname - You said, *"the isp knowing your MAC address"* . No the local router knows the MAC, not the ISP. *"get protonmail to fork over the ip"* . Proton Mail doesn't have your IP because you used Tor. *"What all does the isp i use know about my tor usage"* . You appear to be treading dark and dangerous waters with no idea what you're doing. **I strongly suggest you reconsider!**

Comment: I'm asking for advice so I DO know. Is that not how you learn?................. and guy said "xfinity knows your mac" xfinity is the internet service provider so I was having him clarify.....

Comment: @thatsmynickityname The "guy" who made the comment is the guy who posted the answer ... he was suggesting that because of your many follow up questions, you do not seem to understand the basic foundational knowledge to make your main question answerable without a library of other information. This is a Q&A site, and we can't write a library for each question. The connection from your browser to the file to download has a thousand different pieces, and they all need to be aligned to provide "perfect anonymity". And we can't explain each and every piece.

Comment: *Proton mail setup requires an other existing email.* this is factually **incorrect**. Protonmail does **not** require any previously existing email address.

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov - I think that if you try creating a new Protonmail account using Tor, you'll find that an alternate email is effectively required to get past the spam checker.

Comment: Its not. You do a capatcha.

Comment: @thatsmynickityname - Did you do it with Tor? I did and that's not what I saw.

Comment: Oh shoot maybe not! Damn that's quite a problem. I guess a vpn would be just as affective at hiding the ip from protonmail in this case? I looked into protonmails privacy policy and they comply with federal agencies by providing the ip address, but state for protonmail users that using tor to set up protonmail is a way to hide the ip.. seems contradictory if they require another email.. what about using their onion site to set up a new email with them?